# Current URL /web/guest/HTML generates exception: null in Liferay 6.0.6

Tags: java, struts2, jasper-reports, liferay-6, struts-tags

I develop an example of Struts2 with Jasper Reports and every thing work fine. In my `index.jsp` I have

**`index.jsp`:**

```
<body>
  <a href="HTML.action" target="_blank" >click to generate pdf report</a>
</body>
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<struts>
  <package name="default" extends="struts-default,jasperreports-default">
    <action name="HTML" class="com.tutorialspoint.DataBeanList" method="exporte">
      <result name="success">/index.jsp</result>
    </action>
  </package>
</struts>
```

but when I want to do that with Liferay 6.0.6 I got this error:

```
INFO [PortalImpl:3829] Current URL /web/guest/HTML.action generates exception: null
```

**In my `struts.xml` I have:**

```
<!-- Action pour générer un rapport pdf -->

<package namespace="/reporting" extends="struts-portlet-default,json-default,jasperreports-default" name="reportingview"> 
  <action name="HTML" class="com.xxxxxx.struts2.actions.genererQPpdf" method="exporte">
    <result name="success">/JSPs/reporting/resultQP.jsp</result> 
  </action> 
</package>
```

so any one can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use the struts tags to exclude errors in the code. For example `url` tag could be used to construct the correct link that point to the action.

```
<a href="<s:url namespace="/reporting" action="HTML"/>" target="_blank" >click to generate pdf report</a>
```